# Minimal cURL cross compile for windows

Tags: curl, libcurl, mingw32, cross-compiling

I want to compile cURL from source to use in my Windows DLL project. For this, I installed a Virtual Machine with Ubuntu, downloaded cURL source from http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.37.0.tar.bz2, unpacked and configured it like this:

```
    ./configure --prefix=$HOME/devel/curl3 --disable-ftp --disable-file\
 --disable-ldap --disable-dict --disable-telnet --disable-tftp\
 --disable-rtsp --disable-pop3 --disable-imap --disable-smtp\
 --disable-gopher --disable-ares --disable-debug --without-ssl\
 --without-zlib --without-libidn --build=i586-pc-linux-gnu\
 --host=i386-pc-mingw32 --disable-shared
```

So I have this output:

```
configure: Configured to build curl/libcurl:

  curl version:     7.37.0
  Host setup:       i386-pc-mingw32
  Install prefix:   /home/victor/devel/curl3
  Compiler:         gcc
  SSL support:      no      (--with-{ssl,gnutls,nss,polarssl,cyassl,axtls,winssl,darwinssl} )
  SSH support:      no      (--with-libssh2)
  zlib support:     no      (--with-zlib)
  GSS-API support:  no      (--with-gssapi)
  SPNEGO support:   no      (--with-spnego)
  TLS-SRP support:  no      (--enable-tls-srp)
  resolver:         default (--enable-ares / --enable-threaded-resolver)
  ipv6 support:     no      (--enable-ipv6)
  IDN support:      no      (--with-{libidn,winidn})
  Build libcurl:    Shared=no, Static=yes
  Built-in manual:  enabled
  --libcurl option: enabled (--disable-libcurl-option)
  Verbose errors:   enabled (--disable-verbose)
  SSPI support:     no      (--enable-sspi)
  ca cert bundle:   no
  ca cert path:     no
  LDAP support:     no      (--enable-ldap / --with-ldap-lib / --with-lber-lib)
  LDAPS support:    no      (--enable-ldaps)
  RTSP support:     no      (--enable-rtsp)
  RTMP support:     no      (--with-librtmp)
  metalink support: no      (--with-libmetalink)
  HTTP2 support:    disabled (--with-nghttp2)
  Protocols:        HTTP
```

Then I just do *make & make install* to create the files *(libcurl.a and include/curl/*)*.
Everything just runs fine but the problem is: When I import the generated files, one header is missing:
**sys/socket.h**. This header is not part of a clean MingW32 install and by this, the configure command with --host=i386-pc-mingw32 should not require it, as windows uses winsock, right?

What am I missing here?

Sorry for long question and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what was wrong;

I had to download the mingw32 package and then set it as the toolchain for configure and make commands.
The --host config was also wrong. The toolchain downloaded had to be pointed as "i586-pc-mingw32msvc" and the path was set as:

```
PATH=(path/to/i586ming):$PATH ./configure <options described above>
PATH=(path/to/i586ming):$PATH make
PATH=(path/to/i586ming):$PATH make install
```

And my output was correct.

Answer (score 1):

This question is maybe an old one but here is how I did it..

1. I installed mingw32

   ```
   sudo apt-get install mingw32
   ```
2. Then run `./Configure` with added options **`--host=i586-mingw32msvc LDFLAGS=-mwindows`**:

   ```
   ./configure --host=i586-mingw32msvc LDFLAGS=-mwindows --prefix=path/to/install/to \
   --disable-ftp --disable-file --disable-ldap --disable-dict --disable-telnet \
   --disable-tftp --disable-rtsp --disable-pop3 --disable-imap --disable-smtp \
   --disable-gopher --disable-ares --disable-debug --without-ssl --without-zlib \
   --without-libidn --disable-shared
   ```

   > Modify **`path/to/install/to`** in option **`--prefix=`**.
3. Then:

   ```
   make && make install
   ```